# Unable to locate an element of date picker

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to locate an element of date picker. I tried CssSelector and xpath and everything. Below is the code i tried.

**Code :**

```
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dp1469511990123']"));
        List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

        for (WebElement cell: columns)
        {
             if (cell.getText().equals("21"))
             {
              cell.findElement(By.linkText("21")).click();
              break;
             }
        }
```

Here is HTML code.

**HTML :**

```
<input id="dp1469511990123" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid hasDatepicker ng-not-empty" type="text" ng-disabled="input.p1Edit==0" ng-model="vendor.companyStartedDate" ui-date="comp_st_date" disabled="disabled"/>
```

**Here is the Error:**

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: >{"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='dp1469511990123']"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 10.07 seconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: >http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: >'35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>   System info: host: 'user-PC', ip: '192.168.1.52', os.name: 'Windows 7', >os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` value looks *dynamically generated*, I would use an `ng-model` instead:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[ng-model='vendor.companyStartedDate']"));
```

Count improved readability as a bonus.

And, see if you need to [wait until the presence of the element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903328/771848).

Comment: Yes it is working but it is not selecting date what i have given. Is there any alternate way to select particular date.

Comment: @sandeepkumar not sure which datepicker you're using, but have you tried to read the text value from the input itself rather than from td elements?

Comment: @sandeepkumar You can check this for [selecting date from datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38402746/3122133)