# How to select date from calendar (datepicker )

Tags: c#, selenium, datepicker

I'm new in `Selenium`. I'm using `C#` language.
I would like to select a date from calendar (datepicker), and I must select  two different  calendars  and sendkeys (date).

First calendar: today

Second  calendar : tomorrow

[image: this sreenshot of page]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400383/selenium-webdriver-css-selector-help-for-selecting-date/38402746#38402746) though the implementation in java you can modify it for c#

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario1:**
You have Text Box attached to DatePicker and your TextBox is Enabled to enter details. Then Directly Send the Date to Text Box in Secified format

```
 IWebElement txtBxDatePicker = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TextBoxOfDatePicker"));
txtBxDatePicker.SendKeys("dd/mm/yyy"); //Send in Required Format.
```

**Scenario2:**
You have Text Box attached to DatePicker and your TextBox is Disabled to enter details. Change the Read-Only Attribute of Text box to  false using JavaScriptExecuter.And then Use above code.

Comment: var tomorrow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1);
            var tomorrowyear = new DateTime(tomorrow.Year, tomorrow.Month, tomorrow.Day);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            string baslangıctarihi = today.Day+"/"+today.Month + "/" + today.Year;
            string bitistarihi = tomorrow.Day + "/" + tomorrow.Month + "/" + tomorrow.Year;

Comment: IWebElement gun1 = webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$cbhDetail$datePicker1"));

            gun1.SendKeys(baslangıctarihi);

      
             Thread.Sleep(2000);

            IWebElement gun2 = webdriver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$cbhDetail$datePicker2"));
            gun2.SendKeys(bitistarihi);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

Comment: Are these "ctl00$cbhDetail$datePicker1" and "ctl00$cbhDetail$datePicker2" names of TextBoxes attached to DatePickers or the DatePickers Itself? Can you please share a screenprint of page and its html code?